# How to batch rename a bunch of files of same type inside folders to that the numbers in the name are inside brackets? via terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, rename, batch

Ubuntu 20.04 I have files stored in the following fashion as a example:

Uni -

```
Biology -
   01122023 Class 01 - subj dfsg.txt
   02122023 Class 02 - subj eweg.txt
   03122023 Class 03 - subj ewq.txt
Math - 
   01122023 Class 01 - subj asdfg.txt
   05122023 Class 02 - subj adsdf.txt
   05122023 Class 03 - subj asfv.txt
Physics - 
   01122023 Class 01 - subj asdsfg.txt
   02122023 Class 02 - subj asdff.txt
   04122023 Class 03 - subj aewv.txt
```

How could I batch rename in terminal all files inside every folder so they became:

Uni -

```
Biology -
   [01122023] Class 01 - subj dfsg.txt
   [02122023] Class 02 - subj eweg.txt
   [03122023] Class 03 - subj ewq.txt
Math - 
   [01122023] Class 01 - subj asdfg.txt
   [05122023] Class 02 - subj adsdf.txt
   [05122023] Class 03 - subj asfv.txt
Physics - 
   [01122023] Class 01 - subj asdsfg.txt
   [02122023] Class 02 - subj asdff.txt
   [04122023] Class 03 - subj aewv.txt
```

Comment: Is this homework?